# Is $e^x$ finite almost everywhere even though $\mathop {\lim }\limits_{x \to \infty } {e^x} = + \infty $?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Does $e^x$ is finite almost everywhere even though $\mathop {\lim }\limits_{x \to \infty } {e^x} =  + \infty $? I think it is, but I put on this question to make sure.

I know $f$ being finite a.e. means the measure of set $\{ x:f(x) =  \infty \} $ is zero, so functions like $\frac{1}{x}$, $\tan x$ are finite a.e.

Besides that, can anyone give an example of not finite a.e.? If $e^x$ is finite a.e, then it looks to me that all elementary functions are finite a.e. Thank you!

Comment: Yes, all elementary functions are finite almost everywhere.

Comment: Define $f:\Bbb R\to[0,\infty]$ by $f(x)=\infty$.

Comment: Using $\lfloor x \rfloor$ as the floor function, and the convention that $1/0 = \infty$, I suppose $\dfrac{1}{\lfloor x \rfloor}$ might be an example.

Comment: Your definition of finite functions is correct. Giving $\mathbb{R}$ Lebesgue measure, the function $x\to e^x$ is finite a.e.; in fact, it's finite at every point.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich So "finite almost everywhere" is only defined on $\overline{\mathbb R}$?

Comment: Well yes and no - what you said isn't quite right, but what you meant to say is correct. You meant this: If $f:X\to\Bbb R$ then $f$ is finite almost everywhere. True. Obvious, because $f$ is finite _everywhere_! To get something that's not finite everywhere you clearly need to allow infinite values...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Saying $f$ is blah almost everywhere means, by definition, that the set of points where $f$ is *not* blah has measure zero. The empty set has measure zero. So if $f$ is blah everywhere then $f$ is blah almost everywhere.

In particular, if $f:X\to\Bbb R$ then $f(x)$ is finite for every $x$, hence $f$ is finite almost everywhere.

The notion "finite almost everywhere" doesn't typically come up with functions like $e^t$, because it has real values, so it's obviously finite everywhere. In measure theory we talk about functions $f:X\to[0,\infty]$; *that* sort of function may or may not be finite almost everywhere.

Comment: I think that first "blah everywhere" should be "blah almost everywhere".

Comment: Thanks! A guy should really get things straight when he's complaining about someone else not getting things straight...

Comment: [Muphry's Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Muphry's_law) ;)

Comment: Heh.${}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: Thank you guys. Your argument helps me understand this concept better.